# Can a user / a game developer get their credit back in dollars? If yes, at what cost?

Tags: facebook

You can find every information about [how to give money to facebook](http://www.facebook.com/credits/), but when it comes to take it back…

If I give credits to a user, can he get it back in dollars?

If a user gives me credits, can I turn it into dollars?

If so, how much does it cost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When you redeem Credits with us we will redeem them at the rate of $0.10 per Credit, less a service fee of $0.03 per credit redeemed. If we change the service fee or redemption rate, the redemption rate and service fee in effect at the time you accepted a Credit as consideration will apply to that Credit. We will give you 30 days notice on the Facebook Developer Wiki of changes to the redemption rate or service fee.

I do not believe that an end-user is able to redeem credits. If they were, then Facebook Games might constitute gambling and that would cause problems.

You can find the entire [Facebook Credits Policy here.](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/credits) If you are interested in applying for the credits beta program, [click here.](http://developers.facebook.com/credits) http://developers.facebook.com/credits